# Cast void pointer to integer array

Tags: c, memory, casting

I have a problem where I have a pointer to an area in memory. I would like to use this pointer to create an integer array.

Essentially this is what I have, a pointer to a memory address of size 100*300*2 = 60000 bytes

```
unsigned char *ptr = 0x00000000; // fictional point in memory goes up to 0x0000EA60
```

What i would like to achieve is to examine this memory as an integer array of size 100*150 = 15000 ints = 60000 bytes, like this:

```
unsigned int array[ 100 ][ 150 ];
```

I'm assuming it involves some casting though i'm not sure exactly how to formulate it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you initially acquire the the address in `ptr`?  It could be dangerous to cast an arbitrary pointer to `unsigned int *` if the initial pointer was not aligned to `sizeof int`.  If that happens, then at best your accesses to the memory will be slow due to reads across cache lines.  At worst, it could cause a bus error and your program will halt (depending on your cpu architecture).

Comment: hi chris, just saw your comment. em the address is actually similar to the one in the example and i'm not aquiring it from anywhere - it is an area in memory which i know to be free - working in an embedded environment. i can see what you mean though as this did cause an error when i had it aligned to a character then tried to cast to int. the (temporary) solution i am using is to manually input the address again as above

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can cast the pointer to `unsigned int (*)[150]`. It can then be used **as if** it is a 2D array ("as if", since behavior of `sizeof` is different).

```
unsigned int (*array)[150] = (unsigned int (*)[150]) ptr;
```

Comment: thanks yeah thats what i need. could you elaborate further on how to cast the pointer?

Comment: Just cast it normally i.e. `unsigned int (*array)[150] = (unsigned int (*)[150]) ptr;`

Comment: @nhahtdh : I tried this :`(unsigned long)result.c[2] = 126`and I got this compiler error *lvalue required as left operand of assignment*.`result`is a structure and `c`is of type `unsigned short *`.

Comment: @user2284570: What are you trying to do? From what I see, it is irrelevant to the question here. But what you probably want is `((unsigned long*) result.c)[2] = 126`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your ptr declaration

```
unsigned char *ptr = 0x00000000; // fictional point in memory goes up to 0x0000EA60
```

You can cast ptr to a pointer to whatever type you're treating the block as, in this case array of array of unsigned int. We'll declare a new pointer:

```
unsigned int (*array_2d)[100][150] = (unsigned int (*)[100][150])ptr;
```

Then, access elements by dereferencing and then indexing just as you would for a normal 2d array.

```
(*array_2d)[50][73] = 27;
```

Some `typedef`s would help clean things up, too.

```
typedef unsigned int my_2d_array_t[100][150];
typedef my_2d_array_t *my_2d_array_ptr_t;
my_2d_array_ptr_t array_2d = (my_2d_array_ptr_t)ptr;
(*array_2d)[26][3] = 357;
...
```

And `sizeof` should work properly.

```
sizeof(array_2d); //4, given 32-bit pointer
sizeof(*array_2d); //60000, given 32-bit ints
sizeof((*array_2d)[0]); //600, size of array of 150 ints
sizeof((*array_2d)[0][1]); //4, size of 1 int
```