# Assigning (a pointer to an array of integers) to (a pointer to an integer array cast as a void pointer) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I have come across a C code similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int *a = malloc(200*sizeof(int));

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
      a[i] = i;
    }

    int (*b)[10] = (void*) a;

    printf("\nsizeof(int):\t%d\n", sizeof(int));

    printf("\nb[0]:\t%d\n", b[0]);
    printf("\na:\t%d\n", a);

    printf("\nb[19]:\t%d\n", b[19]);
    printf("\na+190:\t%d\n", a+190);

    printf("\nb[0][8]:\t%d\n", b[0][8]);
    printf("\nb[19][9]:\t%d\n", b[19][9]);

    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding, the line `int (*b)[10] = (void*) a;` is trying to assign pointer `b` (which is supposed to point to an array of 10 integers) to the starting address of array `a` typecast as a void pointer. I would have expected `b[i]` to hold the same data as `a[i]` for `i=0..9` (and any index other than 0 to 9 for `b` resulting in some undefined behavior). However, the program produces outputs similar to the following sample:

```
sizeof(int):    4

b[0]:   9768976

a:      9768976

b[19]:  9769736

a+190:  9769736

b[0][8]:        8

b[19][9]:       199
```

Clearly, `b` has become an array of 20 pointers, with each elemental pointer pointing to a unique portion of the `a` array corresponding to 10 integers (or 40 bytes) each. Can someone please explain what exactly `int (*b)[10] = (void*) a;` does? Specifically, how does the typecast `(void *)` help in distributing the entire `a` across multiple elements of `b`? The above code would not compile without the `(void *)` cast.

Comment: "I would have expected b to be a pointer that can only access the first 10 elements of a"   - so would you also expect that `int *b = (void *)a;` would only be able to access one `int` ?

Comment: No. I guess I did not express myself well in that sentence. I will edit my question to better explain what I meant.

Comment: `b[0]` is an array consisting of the first 10 ints, `b[1]` is the next 10 ints, and so on

Comment: Correct. That's what I figured from the output I posted. I am just not sure how this works inside the `int (*b)[10] = (void*) a;` statement. I could not find other such examples in my online searches. This seems like a way of creating separate pointers for chunks of a large array, something I have not come across earlier.

Comment: It's the same principle as `int *b = (void *)a` except you are pointing to 10 ints instead of pointing to 1 int.

Comment: The cast from `void *` works. A bit more legible would be `int (*b)[10] = (int (*)[10])a;` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454376/cast-void-pointer-to-integer-array although it does not have a lot more information but lead to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size which has a more thorough answer

Comment: @deamentiaemundi The second link was a good read to understand proper declarations for pointers to fixed size arrays. Still, it did not clarify my doubt with the assignment mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this:

```
int *a;
a = malloc(200 * sizeof(int));

int (*b)[10];
b = (void *)a;
```

So, the first line says that `a` should point to an `int`. The second line allocates a block of memory that can hold 200 `int`s, and assigns the address of the start of this block to `a`. The third line says that `b` should point to an array of 10 `int`s. The fourth line says that `b` should be assigned the address held by `a`.

So now `b` points to an array of 10 `int`s starting at the address returned from the call to `malloc()`. Since memory was allocated for 200 `int`s, `b` points to a block of memory that can hold 20 10-element arrays of `int`.

The cast to `void` is needed because `a` was declared to be a pointer to `int`; this allows you to store the value held by `a` in `b`, even though they are of different types. I think that this was a mere convenience in the allocation of the appropriate amount of memory for the array. An alternative method, avoiding the declaration of `a` altogether, would be:

```
int (*b)[10] = malloc(20 * sizeof(*b));
```

This second method might or might not seem a bit more cryptic, depending upon the readers tastes. I guess one advantage of the first method is that it allows you to access the elements of the array both sequentially and as a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly, `b` has become an array of 20 pointers, with each elemental pointer pointing to a unique portion of the `a` array corresponding to 10 integers (or 40 bytes) each.

No, `b` is just a pointer, not an array.  The type `b` points to is array-of-10-`int`s.  Perhaps this would be simpler if you consider it as:

```
typedef int row[10]; // A `row` is an array of 10 ints
row* b = (void*) a;
```

For any pointer `T* p`, `p[n]` is `sizeof (T)` bytes offset from `p[n - 1]` (assuming that `n` and `n - 1` are valid indices, of course).  This case is no different; here `T` is a 10-element `int` array, so each element of `b` is `10 * sizeof (int)` bytes away from its adjacent elements.

> Specifically, how does the typecast `(void *)` help in distributing the entire `a` across multiple elements of `b`? The above code would not compile without the `(void *)` cast.

In C, pointers can be converted between `void*` and `T*` without explicit casting.  The above case uses a `void*` cast for convenience by reducing typing; it allows the right-hand-side to be converted to whatever pointer type is needed by the left-hand-side.

Comment: Your example is finally getting me somewhere. So, `int (*b)[10]` should be interpreted as `b` being a pointer to a _type that consists of a 10-interger array_. Then, after assigning `b` to a larger memory portion (with >10 integers, such as the 200-integers pointed to by `a` in my question), we can access that memory in 10-element chunks by using indices for `b`, starting from `b[0][0..9]` or `(*(b))[0..9]`  for the first 10 elements and `b[19][0..9]` or `(*(b+19))[0..9]` for the last 10.

Comment: @NI3 Also, if you found my answer helpful, you should upvote it. =)

Comment: @jamesdin Thanks. I have upvoted your answer. However, due to my new account, it's not visible yet. I need at least a reputation of 15 for my upvotes to matter.