# Illegal conversion from 'void*' to char(*)?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am trying to allocate 10000 page-tables but unable to compile. I am getting the following error.

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char (*)[(<anonymous> + 1)]' [-fpermissive]
     char (*my_memory)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)] = mmap(NULL,PAGE_SIZE * (100000 + OVERSIZE),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
```

My code as below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long physical_addr;
    uint8_t *buf;
    unsigned long virtual_addr;
    char (*my_memory)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)] = mmap(NULL,PAGE_SIZE * (100000 + OVERSIZE),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i * sizeof(*my_memory) < 10000; i++) {
        my_memory[i][0] = 1;
    }
}
```

Not sure how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: You can't assign an array...

Comment: `my_memory` should be a [pointer to array](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*my_memory%29%5B4096%5D)

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler by chance?

Comment: @Kninnug Right.. my bad.

Comment: `char (*my_memory)[sysconf()] = mmap(....);` should work.  Dummy test: https://ideone.com/0QBeSx. And this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454408/669576.

Comment: does it work with an explicit cast?

Comment: a couple of things: 1) do you have enough memory after deductions for the OS and other programs and your program (between real RAM and the SWAP area on the disk to hold 10000 page sized memory (when a page size is 4096 bytes, that is 409.600,000 bytes?  2) If your running under windows, there is only about 1meg of memory available for the stack and your trying declare a table of ~409meg pointers to char which will consume 409meg * sizeof( char * ) bytes.  3) the call to `mmap()` only returns a single pointer, so suggest something like: `char *myMemory = mmap(....)`;

Comment: I understand the program when allocated will approximately use 40mb of memory. I was able to execute it successfully without using single indexing so believe I do have enough memory. But I was wondering if it was possible to do it with double indexing. I am using Linux by the way.

Comment: @AshwinGopalakrishnan So: (1) Are you using a C++ compiler? (2) Does it work with an explicit cast? Please [edit] your question and clarify these points.

Comment: yes. I am using a c++ compiler.

 I figured out a solution using single indexing. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to an array from a pointer. If you make `my_pointer` a bare pointer, this assignment will work, but you'll lose the ability to do the double-indexing that you're doing in the code you've posted; instead, you'll need to come up with an indexing scheme that allows you to use a 1D-array instead. Your code would then look like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long physical_addr;
    uint8_t *buf;
    unsigned long virtual_addr;
    char *my_memory = mmap(NULL,PAGE_SIZE * (100000 + OVERSIZE),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        my_memory[PAGE_SIZE * i] = 1;
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm sort of inferring what that last loop was intended to do; my interpretation was that you wanted it to set the first byte of every "page" to 1)

Comment: As @Kninnug have already corrected me, it is not an array but a pointer to array..

Comment: OP clearly wants double-indexing. Replacing it by single, calculated indexing works, but I think you can do better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was actually looking for a solution which uses double indexing.

Comment: @AshwinGopalakrishnan You might want to answer some questions that people asked you in the comments below your question. If you want to get a solution better than this one, you should answer these questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use casting to a proper type, since you are actually using the C++ language.

In C, this code would work:

```
char (*my_memory)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)] = mmap(...);
```

Here `my_memory` is a pointer to an array of `char`s. C has built-in conversion from `void*` to any pointer, so the code is legal in C, and does what you want.

If you want to make it work in C++, you should add a cast.

The type of `my_memory` is `char (*)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)]`. So the casting will look like this:

```
char (*my_memory)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)] = static_cast<char (*)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)]>(mmap(...));
```

or, in a less verbose manner:

```
auto my_memory = static_cast<char (*)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)]>(mmap(...));
```

or, if you want to make the code as short as possible (less readable):

```
auto my_memory = (char (*)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)])mmap(...);
```

Some people prefer to have a `typedef` for complex types like pointers to arrays. If you want to go this route, here is the syntax:

```
using my_array_ptr_type = char (*)[sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)];
auto my_memory = static_cast<my_array_ptr_type>(mmap(...));
```